# Derivation Harvey (1984) Logistic Curve

Tags: logistic-curve, differential-equations, continuous-time

Given a logistic function of the form.
 \begin{align*}
 f(t) = \frac{\alpha}{1 + \beta e^{\gamma t}}
\end{align*}
Harvey (1984) differentiates this and takes logs to yield:
 \begin{align*}
\ln  f' = 2 \ln f + \ln \frac{-\beta \gamma}{\alpha} + \gamma t 
\end{align*}

I'm obviously missing something, hoping somebody can help.

Noting, $1 - \frac{f}{\alpha} =  \frac{ \beta e^{\gamma t} }{1 + \beta e^{\gamma t}}$ and $\ln \alpha = 2 \ln f + \ln \beta + \gamma t$.
 \begin{align*}
 f' = - \alpha ( 1 + \beta e^{\gamma t} )^{-2} \gamma \beta e^{\gamma t} \\
 f' = - \gamma f \frac{\beta e^{\gamma t}}{1 + \beta e^{\gamma t}}  = 
 - \gamma f \left( 1 - \frac{f}{\alpha} \right) \\
  f' =  - \gamma f  + \frac{\gamma}{\alpha} f^2 
\end{align*}
Now taking logs (note the mistake below as highlighted by comment with regards to the log of the sum - the derivative is correct as shown in the answer - thanks both)
 \begin{align*}
\ln  f' =  - \ln \gamma - \ln f  + ( \ln \gamma - \ln \alpha + 2 \ln f ) \\
\ln  f' = \ln f - \ln \alpha  \\
\ln  f' = \ln f - (2 \ln f + \ln \beta + \gamma t) \\
\ln  f' = - \ln f - \ln \beta - \gamma t
\end{align*}

Ref:
Harvey, A. (1984). Time series forecasting based on the logistic curve. Journal of the Opera- tional Research Society 35(7), 641–646

Comment: I don't follow the expression after "Now taking logs," because it *looks* like you are replacing $\log(a+b)$ by $\log(a)+\log(b)$ where  $a=-\gamma f$ and $b=\gamma f^2/a.$ That would be invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
\begin{align*}
 f(t) = \frac{\alpha}{1 + \beta e^{\gamma t}}
\end{align*}.
$$
Then
$$
f'(t) = -\alpha (1 + \beta e^{\gamma t})^{-2} \cdot \beta e^{\gamma t} \cdot \gamma
$$
$$
= - \frac{\alpha }{1 + \beta e^{\gamma t}} \cdot \frac{1 }{1 + \beta e^{\gamma t}} \cdot \beta \gamma \cdot e^{\gamma t}
$$
$$
= - f(t) \cdot \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{\alpha }{1 + \beta e^{\gamma t}} \cdot \beta \gamma \cdot e^{\gamma t}
$$
$$
= f(t)^2 \cdot \frac{-\beta \gamma}{\alpha} \cdot e^{\gamma t} 
$$
if we assume $\alpha \neq 0$ so
$$
\log f'(t) = \log \left(-\frac{\beta \gamma}{\alpha}\right) + 2 \log f(t) + \gamma t.
$$

---

Your derivative is correct but it looks like you just put it into a less helpful form; in particular, you turned $f'$ into a sum which won't be very amenable to taking logs. Normally we always try to find something like $f \cdot (1 - f)$ with logistic functions but in this case the main trick was multiplying by $\alpha / \alpha$.